# Getting all URL parameters using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Trying to get a regex (Javascript).

```
Input:   url.html?id=14114&yolo=hahaha
Output:  id=14114
         yolo=hahaha
```

So this is what i have done so far: `(\&|\?)(.*?)\=(.*?)`

**How do I also include the red circled regions?**

[image]

Comment: Do you mean *url.html?id=14114&yolo=hahaha*?

Comment: Why does it need to be regex?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

How about this pattern:

```
(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

Comment: I made a change after he posted. with his help: (\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^\&]+)

Comment: I know this is a little late but this answer will not ignore url fragments (anything after the "#"). Try this one: /[(\?|\&)]([^=]+)\=([^&#]+)/g

Comment: As in the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3
The semicolon(';') character can also be used to delimit parameters, So I think regex pattern should be changed accordingly

Comment: @TMKasun is right, the expression should match "Matrix-Parameters" too! `(?:\?|&|;)([^=]+)=([^&|;]+)`

Comment: No, it is doesn't work. For example: "url.com?a=bat & man", -> (a=bat, &man) (?)

Comment: This pattern assumes param values are nonempty, for example it won't match `a=` in `url.com?a=&b=2`. To allow empty values, use `([^&]*)` instead of `([^&]+)`.

Answer (score 22):

Try using this:

```
[^&?]*?=[^&?]*
```

Comment: What about `;` delimiter for query parameters?

Comment: Doesn't work when I put it in rubular.com