# how to extract parameter(specified pattern string) from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract parameter name from the url path.
parameters are inside {} or follow the first ?(questionmark) or follow & mark in the url.

the url path need to be extracted is in such format :

```
/tt/{pa}/{pb}/?p1=9888&p2=9&p3=98
```

thus the parameters are  `pa`, `pb`,`p1`,`p1`,`p3`

Comment: I don't think you can get all your parameters with a single match

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all URL parameters using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679113/getting-all-url-parameters-using-regex)

Comment: @oliveromahony OP wants more than just the URL parameters, but definitely that could be part of the solution.

Comment: oh ya, sorry - didn't read it fully!

Comment: I considered suggested RFC6570-style URI parsers, but you can't mix variables with and without concrete values (i.e. they can parse the path parameters in the example but they can't parse the query string variables as-is)

Answer (score 2):

Quickest way I can think of is this:

```
[{?&][^}=]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/12ep3rjcF30N_Fq0)

Now I'm also capturing the `{` or `?` or `&` character preceding it, so you'd have to cut that off afterwards:

```js
var inp = '/tt/{pa}/{pb}/?p1=9888&p2=9&p3=98'

var found = inp.match(/[{?&][^}=]+/g).map(function(p){ return p.substring(1); });

document.write(found.join('<br />'));
```

And if you expect something like `/tt/{pa=}/{pb}/?p1={9888&p2=9&p3=98` where `pa=` is a valid param name and/or `{9888` is a valid value, you'd be in trouble. But I doubt this is a serious limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example for extracting separately search variables and variables from path:

```
function extractSearch(search) {
    var result = {};

    search = search || window.location.search;

    if (search.length) {
        search = search.substr(1).split('&');

        for (var i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
            search[i] = search[i].split('=');
            result[decodeURIComponent(search[i][0])] = decodeURIComponent(search[i][1]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function extractFromPath(pattern, url) {
    var keys = [],
        result = {},
        i;

    url = url || window.location.pathname;

    pattern = pattern.replace(/{([^}]+)}/g, function($0, $1) {
        keys.push($1);
        return '([^/]+)';
    });

    pattern = url.match(new RegExp('^' + pattern));

    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        result[keys[i]] = pattern[i + 1];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Example of use:

```
// Object {a: "10", b: "20"}
extractSearch('?a=10&b=20');

// Object {pa: "1", pb: "2"}
extractFromPath('/tt/{pa}/{pb}', '/tt/1/2/?p1=9888&p2=9&p3=98');
```

Eventually you can combine it by:

```
function getParameters(pattern, path) {
    var result,
        tmp;

    path = path.split('?');

    result = extractFromPath(pattern, path[0]);

    if (path[1] !== void 0) {
        tmp = extractSearch('?' + path[1]);

        for (var param in tmp) {
            result[param] = tmp[param];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

// Object {pa: "1", pb: "2", a: "10", b: "20"}
getParameters('/tt/{pa}/{pb}', '/tt/1/2?a=10&b=20');
```