# How to filter specific params from URL?

Tags: javascript

I need to filter out params from my URL. 
So for example:

```
URL = test1/test2/:test3
```

some filter output = `test3`

```
URL = test1/:test2/test3
```

some filter output = `test2`

```
URL = :test1/test2/test3
```

some filter output = `test1`

```
URL = :test1/test2/test3/:test4
```

some filter output = `test1, test4`

I've tried some REGEX and substring filters myself, but I can't really get it to work considering all possible URL examples above in 1 filter.

Comment: Why don't you show us your regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all URL parameters using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679113/getting-all-url-parameters-using-regex)

Comment: Add the code of what you have tried to your question

Comment: For example URL.substring(URL.indexOf(":")+1) works for example 1 with output 'test 3'. But it doesnt work for the remainders. Also the 'duplicate suggestions' are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

https://regex101.com/r/Jh0BVJ/3/

```js
regex = new RegExp(/:(?<match>(?:[\w\-.~:?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]*)\d+)+/gm)
url = ":test1/test2/test3/:test4"
console.log(url.match(regex))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually just creating another router:

https://github.com/krasimir/navigo

I've never used navigo, but it looks powerful enough:

```
router
  .on('/user/:id/:action', function (params) {
    // If we have http://example.com/user/42/save as a url then
    // params.id = 42
    // params.action = save
  })
  .resolve();

router.notFound(function (query) {
  // ...
});
```

Now use it:

```
router.navigate('/products/list');

//Or even with FQDN:
router.navigate('http://example.com/products/list', true);
```

Comment: My question is not related on how to navigate or use route. I need to filter out the parameters and save them in a list (for instance)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const REGEX = /\:([A-z0-9-._~:?#\[\]\@\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\=]+)/g;

function findMatches(re, str, matches = []) {
   const m = re.exec(str)
   m && matches.push(m[1]) && findMatches(re, str, matches)
   return matches
}

const urls = [
  'test1/test2/:test3',
  'test1/:test2/test3',
  ':test1/test2/test3',
  ':test1/test2/test3/:test4',
];


const values = urls.map(url => findMatches(REGEX, url));

console.log(values);
```